# input type=submit not returning anything

Tags: php, post, submit, form-submit

Team, could you please help me on this? I am trying to get the values from a form to alter those values on mysql. It is a sell operation that requires a value and this will be put in the database.
I have a check box that allows the user to select which objects he wants to be sold them according to this selection I am creating a new table bellow with objects selected and POST methods for the values. However this is not doing exactly what I need, I do not know how to relate each value to the correct object. Could you help ? This is the part that I am stuck at, more specifically on second isset:

```
if(isset($_POST['publicar'])){//to run PHP script on submit
                if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])){

                    echo "<tr><td>Sites a Publicar</td><td>Valor</td></tr>";
                    foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $selected){
                        echo"<tr><td>".$selected."</td><td><input type=number name=valor_site[]></td></tr>";
                        $_SESSION['lista_public[]']=$selected;

                    }

                    echo"<tr><td><input type='submit' name='submit_valor' value='Submit' /></td></tr>";
                }
            }
if(isset($_POST['submit_valor'])){
                if(!empty($_POST['valor_site'])){
                    foreach($_POST['valor_site'] as $valor_site){
                        echo $selected." tem valor ".$valor_site;
                    } 
                }
            }
```

Comment: echo $selected." tem valor ".$valor_site;    this line is the problem. It doesn't recognize this variable "$selected" and even so it would not work as I need.

Comment: `$selected` is only defined in the `foreach` block. It looks like you need to pull that value from the `$_SESSION` object.

Comment: I tried that, but it also takes only the last value of the SESSION, if I have more than one value like: "A" and "B" it displays "B has value=x and B has value=y" and I need to match the values with the objects

Comment: That's because you can only store one value at a time to a single key on SESSION. However, the value you store there could be an array. Create an array before the $selected loop, store your keys in it, then store that array in SESSION after the loop.

Comment: Could you show how it would be? Sorry I think my brain has stuck

Comment: I though it was being done already with the lista_public[]

Comment: The string 'lista_public[]' is not an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use array

```
    $temp = array()
    if(isset($_POST['publicar'])){//to run PHP script on submit
            if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])){
                echo "<tr><td>Sites a Publicar</td><td>Valor</td></tr>";
                foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $selected){
                    echo"<tr><td>".$selected."</td><td><input type=number name=valor_site[]></td></tr>";
                    $temp[]=$selected;

                }
                $_SESSION['lista_public'] = $temp;
                echo"<tr><td><input type='submit' name='submit_valor' value='Submit' /></td></tr>";
            }
        }
    if(isset($_POST['submit_valor'])){
    if(!empty($_POST['valor_site'])){
    $i = 0;
    $temp = $_SESSION['lista_public'];
    foreach($_POST['valor_site'] as $valor_site){
        echo $temp[$i++]." tem valor ".$valor_site;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```php
$_SESSION['lista_public[]']=$selected;
```

This overwrites the value stored in `$_SESSION['lista_public[]']` every time. What I'm suggesting is:

```
$_SESSION['lista_public'] = array();
if(isset($_POST['publicar'])){//to run PHP script on submit
    if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])){
        echo "<tr><td>Sites a Publicar</td><td>Valor</td></tr>";
        foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $selected){
            echo"<tr><td>".$selected."</td><td><input type=number name=valor_site[]></td></tr>";
            $_SESSION['lista_public'][] = $selected;
        }

        echo"<tr><td><input type='submit' name='submit_valor' value='Submit' /></td></tr>";
    }
}

if(isset($_POST['submit_valor'])){
    if(!empty($_POST['valor_site'])){
        $i = 0;
        foreach($_POST['valor_site'] as $valor_site){
            echo $_SESSION['lista_public'][$i++]." tem valor ".$valor_site;
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: I liked your idea to set the SESSION with the values, since I will need it in other pages. But using this way I get the some errors like:  Undefined offset: 2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\sites_owner.php on line 56. What is the reason for it if I have initialized incremented the counter "$i"  correctly

Comment: You should probably check the length of the array before indexing into it. I just wrote the quick version.